# C# Capture screen to 8-bit (256 color) bitmap

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, bitmap, screen-capture

I'm using this code to capture the screen:

```
public Bitmap CaptureWindow(IntPtr handle)
{
    // get te hDC of the target window
    IntPtr hdcSrc = User32.GetWindowDC(handle);
    // get the size
    User32.RECT windowRect = new User32.RECT();
    User32.GetWindowRect(handle, ref windowRect);
    int width = windowRect.right - windowRect.left;
    int height = windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top;
    // create a device context we can copy to
    IntPtr hdcDest = GDI32.CreateCompatibleDC(hdcSrc);
    // create a bitmap we can copy it to,
    // using GetDeviceCaps to get the width/height
    IntPtr hBitmap = GDI32.CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcSrc, width, height);
    // select the bitmap object
    IntPtr hOld = GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hBitmap);
    // bitblt over
    GDI32.BitBlt(hdcDest, 0, 0, width, height, hdcSrc, 0, 0, GDI32.SRCCOPY);
    // restore selection
    GDI32.SelectObject(hdcDest, hOld);
    // clean up 
    GDI32.DeleteDC(hdcDest);
    User32.ReleaseDC(handle, hdcSrc);
    // get a .NET image object for it
    Bitmap img = Image.FromHbitmap(hBitmap);
    // free up the Bitmap object
    GDI32.DeleteObject(hBitmap);
    return img;
}
```

I then want to convert the bitmap to 256 colors (8 bit).  I tried this code but get an error about not being able to create an Image from an indexed bitmap format:

```
Bitmap img8bit = new Bitmap(img.Width,img.Height,
                           System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(img8bit);
g.DrawImage(img,new Point(0,0));
```

I did see some examples to convert bitmaps between different formats, but in my case I'm looking for the best way to do this while capturing from the screen.  For example, if there is a method that will work better by creating an 8-bit bitmap to begin with and then blit the screen to that, that would be preferred over caputring screen to comptible bitmap first and then converting it.  Unless it's better to capture then convert anyway.

I have a program written in C++ using Borland Builder 6.0 VCL, and I'm trying to memic that.  In that case it is a simple matter of setting the pixel format for VCL's TBitmap object.  I notice Bitmap.PixelFormat is read-only in .NET, ugh.

**Update:** In my case I don't think the answer is as complex as some other usage that requires figuring out the best palette entries, because Graphics.GetHalftonePalette using the screen DC should be fine, since my original bitmap comes from the screen, not just any random bitmap that might come from a file/email/download/etc.  I beleive there is something that can be done with maybe 20 lines of code that involves DIBs and GetHalftonePalette -- just can't find it yet.

Comment: Are you always going to be capturing the entire screen? If so, there's a built-in way to do that with .NET, `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`.

Comment: The `PixelFormat` property is read only, but there's a Bitmap constructor that lets you specify the pixel format. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z132tat.aspx.

Comment: @eselk did you ever get any further with this? :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Converting a full color bitmap to 8bpp is a difficult operation.  It requires creating a histogram of all the colors in the image and creating a palette that contains an optimized set of colors that best map to the original colors.  Then using a technique like dithering or error diffusion to replace the pixels whose colors don't have an exact match with the palette.

This is best left to a professional graphics library, something like ImageTools.  There is one cheap way that can be tricked in the .NET framework.  You can use the GIF encoder, a file format that has 256 colors.  The result isn't the greatest, it uses dithering and that can be pretty visible sometimes.  Then again, if you really cared about image quality then you wouldn't use 8bpp anyway.

```
    public static Bitmap ConvertTo8bpp(Image img) {
        var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream();   // Don't use using!!!
        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        ms.Position = 0;
        return new Bitmap(ms);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks.  It seems like at the Windows API level there are ways to bitblt() between device contexts of different pixel formats and that the OS takes care of these details for you.  I could be wrong though, and if no one posts any answers along those lines I'll accept this answer.  Quality isn't a huge issue obviously but whatever method VCL is using does produce decent results, especially for reading text.  I might have to look at their source code to see what they do and then try to translate to .NET or pinvokes.

Comment: Accepted.  After looking through the VCL source code I do see that it is doing A LOT of work.  I assumed the Win32 API would be doing most of the work, but I guess not.  Sucks that going from a legacy library like VCL to .NET and now I have to do more work for something that was simple before, but that's life.  GIF will not work for me as the dithering is awful, converting to 256 colors the way VCL does it is actually pretty nice looking for most business apps/basic screens (not so much for photos or game screen captures).

Comment: I do find it interesting that the VCL method produces identical results to doing a screen cap, paste in MSPaint, save as 256-color bitmap to file... but I suppose they might just be using the same algorithm.

Comment: +1, but may I ask, why not use `using`? I'm using `using` and it's all fine.

Comment: @GSerg - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2193222/loading-saving-and-then-loading-an-image-again-throws-a-generic-error-occurre

Answer (score 1):

Capture the screen using a regular PixelFormat and then use Bitmap.Clone() to convert it to an optimized 256 indexed color like this:

```
public static Bitmap CaptureScreen256()
{
    Rectangle bounds = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;

    using (Bitmap Temp = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb))
    {
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Temp))
        {
            g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Temp.Size);
        }

        return Temp.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, bounds.Width, bounds.Height), PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);
    }
}
```