# Why won't GDI+ save this image?

Tags: c#, image, gdi+

I'm trying to save a file using GDI+, but I just get a "A generic error occurred in GDI+" exception. The code works fine for almost every photo but this one (we handle thousands a day for years and this is the first I've heard of it). I think it might have something to do with exif data or perhaps something else odd from the photographers camera or editor.

[Here's the photo in question](http://tfv.co/gdi_err.jpg)

And here is code to reproduce the error with this photo:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var img = Image.FromFile("Err.jpg"))
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

How am I supposed to handle this in GDI+? Is there a way to strip out the extra stuff that is causing the problem?

Comment: Your image is missing. You should post it here instead.

Comment: What do you mean by "Your image is missing"? The url seems to work for me. Are you getting a 404?

Comment: Well, I see it now.  I was getting an "Image not found"

Comment: @EdS. You weren't the only one.

Comment: @Ed S. I uploaded the image like you suggested. But I'm not sure why you weren't able to see it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: No error.  The way you are disposing the MemoryStream is asking for trouble, don't ever try to create an image from it.  That will indeed bomb with a generic exception if you ever try to do anything with that image.

Comment: Works fine for me, the only difference I did was put it in the H drive so I had H:// in front. Are you sure this is the code that's giving the error? Can you try-catch the stack trace and show us?

Comment: This is just a test to show the error. It's not intended to be production code. Unfortunately it looks like SO changed the image when I uploaded it. I'll try to find another place to put the file that won't change it and that is accessible to everybody.

Comment: @HansPassant: What do you mean by “asking for trouble”?

Comment: @minitech: Brian's code writes content to the `MemoryStream` and then immediately calls its `Dispose` method.  I think Hans is overreacting, this is the sort of thing you expect from a minimal repro.

Comment: I updated the photo and verified that I was able to get the error when I saved it locally (I clicked "Save Link As...").

Comment: @minitech: Image keeps a reference to the stream. If you dispose the stream before you are done with the image, you will get exceptions when you try to use the image.

Comment: @Brian: You’re using `using`. The exception will be compile-time. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @minitech: the compiler doesn't know that it is still being used. Check out this answer, it discusses it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2193250/320. As a note, the way I am using it in my example is fine since I am disposing the image at the same time.

Comment: @Brian: You’re writing to the stream, so it shouldn’t be an issue, should it? Anyways, thanks for clearing that up. I was really confused =)

Comment: @minitech, you are correct. Hans was just saying that if you try to create an image from it (typically the reason you would store it in a MemoryStream), disposing it would cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that converting the image to a bmp first solves the problem. It would be nice to find a method that is more efficient (doesn't require multiple images to be created and loaded into memory), but this is the best I've found so far.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var path = @"gdi_err.jpg";
    using (var img1 = Image.FromFile(path))
    using (var ms1 = new MemoryStream())
    {
        img1.Save(ms1, ImageFormat.Bmp);
        ms1.Position = 0;
        using (var img2 = Image.FromStream(ms1))
        using (var ms2 = new MemoryStream())
        {
            img2.Save(ms2, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exif profile of your image seems to be the problem. When I remove it I can save the image to the memorystream. I used [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com) to remove the exif profile.

```
using (MagickImage magickImage = new MagickImage())
{
  using (var magickStream = new MemoryStream())
  {
    magickImage.Read(@"gdi_err.jpg");
    magickImage.Strip();
    magickImage.Write(magickStream);
    magickStream.Position = 0;

    // This part is just here to demonstrate that saving the image works.
    // You don't need it because magickStream already contains the data you want.
    using (Image image = Image.FromStream(magickStream))
    {
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
        image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
      }
    }
  }
}
```